Automation - Trigger & procedure
I am having problem to create a trigger in Netcool which could clear the alarm in integrated tool with netcool omnibus
therefore incidentStatus=1 value is set and it is already clearing alarm in Netcool.
but I want to clear same alarm from source tool (Origin of Alarm) basis on incidentID (Part of integrated tool) showing in SuppKey field in Netcool Database. therefore I want to pass the value of IncidentId from SuppKey showing in select * from status at netcool database, so that same alarm would be clear coming at source tool.
Moreover, I created a Incidnetclose.pl and successfully tested (manually) to clear the alarm in source tool. so placing this Incidentclose.pl in trigger to automate
I created a procedure where I placed incidentclose.pl at object server path for 1 min interval, and also created a trigger in which I put
begin 

execute "Procedure name"        -------- incidentClose.pl defined in path in Procedure. 

End 

but defining when condition incidentStatus = 1 is having  problem in trigger who can run the procedure when IncidentStatus = 1 is coming in Netcool database.
I am new in netcool.
